# Google Drive API origin_mismatch Error

Tags: google-drive-api

Hello I am trying to learn the Google Drivre API by using the default Quick Start guide.

[QuickStart](http://imgur.com/OpAgNih)

I got the client ID made, added it to the correct places, and the App will now Authorize on the server.

The problem I am having now is, that it gives me this Origin Mismatch Error, and no matter what scopes I add I am stuck.

I am pretty new to APIS but am trying to learn.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2013 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

 "use strict";

/**
 * @fileoverview Common utility functionality for Google Drive Realtime API,
 * including authorization and file loading. This functionality should serve
 * mostly as a well-documented example, though is usable in its own right.
 */


/**
 * @namespace Realtime client utilities namespace.
 */
var rtclient = rtclient || {}


/**
 * OAuth 2.0 scope for installing Drive Apps.
 * @const
 */
rtclient.INSTALL_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install'


/**
 * OAuth 2.0 scope for opening and creating files.
 * @const
 */
rtclient.FILE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'


/**
 * OAuth 2.0 scope for accessing the user's ID.
 * @const
 */
rtclient.OPENID_SCOPE = 'openid'


/**
 * MIME type for newly created Realtime files.
 * @const
 */
rtclient.REALTIME_MIMETYPE = 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk';


/**
 * Parses the hash parameters to this page and returns them as an object.
 * @function
 */
rtclient.getParams = function() {
  var params = {};
  var hashFragment = window.location.hash;
  if (hashFragment) {
    // split up the query string and store in an object
    var paramStrs = hashFragment.slice(1).split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < paramStrs.length; i++) {
      var paramStr = paramStrs[i].split("=");
      params[paramStr[0]] = unescape(paramStr[1]);
    }
  }
  console.log(params);
  return params;
}


/**
 * Instance of the query parameters.
 */
rtclient.params = rtclient.getParams();


/**
 * Fetches an option from options or a default value, logging an error if
 * neither is available.
 * @param options {Object} containing options.
 * @param key {string} option key.
 * @param defaultValue {Object} default option value (optional).
 */
rtclient.getOption = function(options, key, defaultValue) {
  var value = options[key] == undefined ? defaultValue : options[key];
  if (value == undefined) {
    console.error(key + ' should be present in the options.');
  }
  console.log(value);
  return value;
}


/**
 * Creates a new Authorizer from the options.
 * @constructor
 * @param options {Object} for authorizer. Two keys are required as mandatory, these are:
 *
 *    1. "clientId", the Client ID from the console
 */
rtclient.Authorizer = function(options) {
  this.clientId = rtclient.getOption(options, 'clientId');
  // Get the user ID if it's available in the state query parameter.
  this.userId = rtclient.params['userId'];
  this.authButton = document.getElementById(rtclient.getOption(options, 'authButtonElementId'));
}


/**
 * Start the authorization process.
 * @param onAuthComplete {Function} to call once authorization has completed.
 */
rtclient.Authorizer.prototype.start = function(onAuthComplete) {
  var _this = this;
  gapi.load('auth:client,drive-realtime,drive-share', function() {
    _this.authorize(onAuthComplete);
  });
}


/**
 * Reauthorize the client with no callback (used for authorization failure).
 * @param onAuthComplete {Function} to call once authorization has completed.
 */
rtclient.Authorizer.prototype.authorize = function(onAuthComplete) {
  var clientId = this.clientId;
  var userId = this.userId;
  var _this = this;

  var handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      _this.authButton.disabled = true;
      _this.fetchUserId(onAuthComplete);
    } else {
      _this.authButton.disabled = false;
      _this.authButton.onclick = authorizeWithPopup;
    }
  };

  var authorizeWithPopup = function() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: [
        rtclient.INSTALL_SCOPE,
        rtclient.FILE_SCOPE,
        rtclient.OPENID_SCOPE
      ],
      user_id: userId,
      immediate: false
    }, handleAuthResult);
    console.log(clientId);
  };

  // Try with no popups first.
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: [
      rtclient.INSTALL_SCOPE,
      rtclient.FILE_SCOPE,
      rtclient.OPENID_SCOPE
    ],
    user_id: userId,
    immediate: true
  }, handleAuthResult);
}


/**
 * Fetch the user ID using the UserInfo API and save it locally.
 * @param callback {Function} the callback to call after user ID has been
 *     fetched.
 */
rtclient.Authorizer.prototype.fetchUserId = function(callback) {
  var _this = this;
  gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
    gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
      if (resp.id) {
        _this.userId = resp.id;
      }
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  });
};

/**
 * Creates a new Realtime file.
 * @param title {string} title of the newly created file.
 * @param mimeType {string} the MIME type of the new file.
 * @param callback {Function} the callback to call after creation.
 */
rtclient.createRealtimeFile = function(title, mimeType, callback) {
  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
    gapi.client.drive.files.insert({
      'resource': {
        mimeType: mimeType,
        title: title
      }
    }).execute(callback);
  });
}


/**
 * Fetches the metadata for a Realtime file.
 * @param fileId {string} the file to load metadata for.
 * @param callback {Function} the callback to be called on completion, with signature:
 *
 *    function onGetFileMetadata(file) {}
 *
 * where the file parameter is a Google Drive API file resource instance.
 */
rtclient.getFileMetadata = function(fileId, callback) {
  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
    gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      'fileId' : fileId
    }).execute(callback);
  });
}


/**
 * Parses the state parameter passed from the Drive user interface after Open
 * With operations.
 * @param stateParam {Object} the state query parameter as an object or null if
 *     parsing failed.
 */
rtclient.parseState = function(stateParam) {
  try {
    var stateObj = JSON.parse(stateParam);
    return stateObj;
  } catch(e) {
    return null;
  }
}


/**
 * Handles authorizing, parsing query parameters, loading and creating Realtime
 * documents.
 * @constructor
 * @param options {Object} options for loader. Four keys are required as mandatory, these are:
 *
 *    1. "clientId", the Client ID from the console
 *    2. "initializeModel", the callback to call when the file is loaded.
 *    3. "onFileLoaded", the callback to call when the model is first created.
 *
 * and one key is optional:
 *
 *    1. "defaultTitle", the title of newly created Realtime files.
 */
rtclient.RealtimeLoader = function(options) {
  // Initialize configuration variables.
  this.onFileLoaded = rtclient.getOption(options, 'onFileLoaded');
  this.newFileMimeType = rtclient.getOption(options, 'newFileMimeType', rtclient.REALTIME_MIMETYPE);
  this.initializeModel = rtclient.getOption(options, 'initializeModel');
  this.registerTypes = rtclient.getOption(options, 'registerTypes', function(){});
  this.afterAuth = rtclient.getOption(options, 'afterAuth', function(){})
  this.autoCreate = rtclient.getOption(options, 'autoCreate', false); // This tells us if need to we automatically create a file after auth.
  this.defaultTitle = rtclient.getOption(options, 'defaultTitle', 'New Realtime File');
  this.authorizer = new rtclient.Authorizer(options);
}


/**
 * Redirects the browser back to the current page with an appropriate file ID.
 * @param fileIds {Array.} the IDs of the files to open.
 * @param userId {string} the ID of the user.
 */
rtclient.RealtimeLoader.prototype.redirectTo = function(fileIds, userId) {
  var params = [];
  if (fileIds) {
    params.push('fileIds=' + fileIds.join(','));
  }
  if (userId) {
    params.push('userId=' + userId);
  }

  // Naive URL construction.
  var newUrl = params.length == 0 ? './' : ('./#' + params.join('&'));
  // Using HTML URL re-write if available.
  if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
    window.history.replaceState("Google Drive Realtime API Playground", "Google Drive Realtime API Playground", newUrl);
  } else {
    window.location.href = newUrl;
  }
  // We are still here that means the page didn't reload.
  rtclient.params = rtclient.getParams();
  for (var index in fileIds) {
    gapi.drive.realtime.load(fileIds[index], this.onFileLoaded, this.initializeModel, this.handleErrors);
  }
}


/**
 * Starts the loader by authorizing.
 */
rtclient.RealtimeLoader.prototype.start = function() {
  // Bind to local context to make them suitable for callbacks.
  var _this = this;
  this.authorizer.start(function() {
    if (_this.registerTypes) {
      _this.registerTypes();
    }
    if (_this.afterAuth) {
      _this.afterAuth();
    }
    _this.load();
  });
}


/**
 * Handles errors thrown by the Realtime API.
 */
rtclient.RealtimeLoader.prototype.handleErrors = function(e) {
  if(e.type == gapi.drive.realtime.ErrorType.TOKEN_REFRESH_REQUIRED) {
    authorizer.authorize();
  } else if(e.type == gapi.drive.realtime.ErrorType.CLIENT_ERROR) {
    alert("An Error happened: " + e.message);
    window.location.href= "/";
  } else if(e.type == gapi.drive.realtime.ErrorType.NOT_FOUND) {
    alert("The file was not found. It does not exist or you do not have read access to the file.");
    window.location.href= "/";
  }
};


/**
 * Loads or creates a Realtime file depending on the fileId and state query
 * parameters.
 */
rtclient.RealtimeLoader.prototype.load = function() {
  var fileIds = rtclient.params['fileIds'];
  if (fileIds) {
    fileIds = fileIds.split(',');
  }
  var userId = this.authorizer.userId;
  var state = rtclient.params['state'];

  // Creating the error callback.
  var authorizer = this.authorizer;


  // We have file IDs in the query parameters, so we will use them to load a file.
  if (fileIds) {
    for (var index in fileIds) {
      gapi.drive.realtime.load(fileIds[index], this.onFileLoaded, this.initializeModel, this.handleErrors);
    }
    return;
  }

  // We have a state parameter being redirected from the Drive UI. We will parse
  // it and redirect to the fileId contained.
  else if (state) {
    var stateObj = rtclient.parseState(state);
    // If opening a file from Drive.
    if (stateObj.action == "open") {
      fileIds = stateObj.ids;
      userId = stateObj.userId;
      this.redirectTo(fileIds, userId);
      return;
    }
  }

  if (this.autoCreate) {
    this.createNewFileAndRedirect();
  }
}


/**
 * Creates a new file and redirects to the URL to load it.
 */
rtclient.RealtimeLoader.prototype.createNewFileAndRedirect = function() {
  // No fileId or state have been passed. We create a new Realtime file and
  // redirect to it.
  var _this = this;
  rtclient.createRealtimeFile(this.defaultTitle, this.newFileMimeType, function(file) {
    if (file.id) {
      _this.redirectTo([file.id], _this.authorizer.userId);
    }
    // File failed to be created, log why and do not attempt to redirect.
    else {
      console.error('Error creating file.');
      console.error(file);
    }
  });
}
```

and the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google Drive Realtime quickstart</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">

  <!-- Load the Realtime libraries. -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

  <!-- Load the utility library. -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="realtime-client-utils.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Start Realtime when the body has loaded. -->
<body onLoad='startRealtime()'>

  <h1>Drive Realtime API :: quickstart</h1>

  <button id="authorizeButton" disabled>You must authorize</button>

  <p>These text areas are on the same page. You can also <a target="_blank" href="#">open them on separate users'
  browsers</a> and they will remain synchronized.</p>

  <!-- Text areas that will be used as our collaborative controls. -->
  <textarea id="editor1" rows="15" cols="50" disabled="true"></textarea>
  <textarea id="editor2" rows="15" cols="50" disabled="true"></textarea>
  <br />

  <!-- Undo and redo buttons. -->
  <button id="undoButton" disabled>Undo</button>
  <button id="redoButton" disabled>Redo</button>

  <script>
    /**
     * This function is called the first time that the Realtime model is created
     * for a file. This function should be used to initialize any values of the
     * model. In this case, we just create the single string model that will be
     * used to control our text box. The string has a starting value of 'Hello
     * Realtime World!', and is named 'text'.
     * @param model {gapi.drive.realtime.Model} the Realtime root model object.
     */
    function initializeModel(model) {
      var string = model.createString('Hello Realtime World!');
      model.getRoot().set('text', string);
    }

    /**
     * This function is called when the Realtime file has been loaded. It should
     * be used to initialize any user interface components and event handlers
     * depending on the Realtime model. In this case, create a text control binder
     * and bind it to our string model that we created in initializeModel.
     * @param doc {gapi.drive.realtime.Document} the Realtime document.
     */
    function onFileLoaded(doc) {
      var string = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text');

      // Keeping one box updated with a String binder.
      var textArea1 = document.getElementById('editor1');
      gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(string, textArea1);

      // Keeping one box updated with a custom EventListener.
      var textArea2 = document.getElementById('editor2');
      var updateTextArea2 = function(e) {
        textArea2.value = string;
      };
      string.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.TEXT_INSERTED, updateTextArea2);
      string.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.TEXT_DELETED, updateTextArea2);
      textArea2.onkeyup = function() {
        string.setText(textArea2.value);
      };
      updateTextArea2();

      // Enabling UI Elements.
      textArea1.disabled = false;
      textArea2.disabled = false;

      // Add logic for undo button.
      var model = doc.getModel();
      var undoButton = document.getElementById('undoButton');
      var redoButton = document.getElementById('redoButton');

      undoButton.onclick = function(e) {
        model.undo();
      };
      redoButton.onclick = function(e) {
        model.redo();
      };

      // Add event handler for UndoRedoStateChanged events.
      var onUndoRedoStateChanged = function(e) {
        undoButton.disabled = !e.canUndo;
        redoButton.disabled = !e.canRedo;
      };
      model.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.UNDO_REDO_STATE_CHANGED, onUndoRedoStateChanged);
    }

    /**
     * Options for the Realtime loader.
     */
    var realtimeOptions = {
      /**
       * Client ID from the console.
       */
      clientId: '1027242878238-cuom4vgu063ane3146ianitr9qvqh4mq.apps.googleusercontent.com',

      /**
       * The ID of the button to click to authorize. Must be a DOM element ID.
       */
      authButtonElementId: 'authorizeButton',

      /**
       * Function to be called when a Realtime model is first created.
       */
      initializeModel: initializeModel,

      /**
       * Autocreate files right after auth automatically.
       */
      autoCreate: true,

      /**
       * The name of newly created Drive files.
       */
      defaultTitle: "New Realtime Quickstart File",

      /**
       * The MIME type of newly created Drive Files. By default the application
       * specific MIME type will be used:
       *     application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.
       */
      newFileMimeType: null, // Using default.

      /**
       * Function to be called every time a Realtime file is loaded.
       */
      onFileLoaded: onFileLoaded,

      /**
       * Function to be called to inityalize custom Collaborative Objects types.
       */
      registerTypes: null, // No action.

      /**
       * Function to be called after authorization and before loading files.
       */
      afterAuth: null // No action.
    }

    /**
     * Start the Realtime loader with the options.
     */
    function startRealtime() {
      var realtimeLoader = new rtclient.RealtimeLoader(realtimeOptions);
      realtimeLoader.start();
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[And finally my OAUTH setting!](http://imgur.com/OpAgNih)